# How to share file in Rails to users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some pdf files in public/data I would like to share files to user ( the user can write url file and can see the file).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place file in `public` folder in root of your application. For example, if you have foo.txt document, user can type `http://you_url/foo.txt` and see it.